# PHP ip2long only picking up last entry if input from a text file

Tags: php, fopen, fgets

Sorry if this has been asked before, but my search didn't yield much help. I'm having some issues incorporating the PHP built-in function 'ip2long' in my script. The input IP addresses are coming from a text file and the function is only picking up the last address on the list to do the conversion on. I'm running the script on a 32-bit machine if that gives a clue to the problem.

```
<?php
$text_file = 'ip.txt';
//begin reading text file
if (($file = fopen($text_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    echo "Begin IP Convertion \n";
    while ($line = fgets($file)) {
        echo "$line = " . ip2long($line) . "\n";
    }
} else {echo "No file found \n";}

fclose($file);
?>
```

Here are the contents of the ip.txt file:

```
127.0.0.1
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
4.4.4.4
```

Result upon running the script:

```
# php ip.php
Begin IP Convertion 
127.0.0.1
 = 
1.1.1.1
 = 
2.2.2.2
 = 
3.3.3.3
 = 
4.4.4.4 = 67372036
#
```

-Jon

Comment: To answer my own question: it looks like there were spaces next to those IP addresses causing the function to not work properly. Adding the 'chop' function to the script solved my problems.

    ip2long(chop($line))

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the newlines from the string using something like `trim`

```
<?php
$text_file = 'ip.txt';
//begin reading text file
if (($file = fopen($text_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    echo "Begin IP Convertion \n";
    while ($line = fgets($file)) {
        echo trim($line) . " = " . ip2long(trim($line)) . "\n";
    }
} else {echo "No file found \n";}

fclose($file);
?>
```